# Website in Malayalam language

Tags: unicode

I am about to design a website in Malayalam. I am in search of @ font face rule. I want to use malayalam unicode font. Sometimes, the browser does not display some characters well. For example, when I visit the site [Pravasikairali.com](http://www.pravasikairali.com) it is always displayed well. But when I visit some other sites, it is not displayed well.
Can I get the best @ fontface rule recognised by all browsers.

Comment: Unicode fonts are universal and hence unicode malayalam font should be supported in most modern browsers, applications and OS. Which OS and browser do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tryout meera unicode font. It works for me.